# How to add constant integer value to integer column?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with 3 columns and one of the columns is an integer. I want to add an integer value to it.

```
id person age
1  person1 4
2  person4 5
3  person3 7
```

I want to add a constant 20 to their age so that their ages will be 24,25 and 27 respectively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a new column and add 20 in a age column by

```
dataFrame.withColumn("age", col("age") + 20)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `UserDefinedFunction` that calculates potentially more complex expressions. In Java 8 it can look something like this:

```
    UserDefinedFunction doAge = udf(
            (Integer age) -> age+20, DataTypes.IntegerType
    );

    dataFrame = dataFrame.withColumn("age",doAge.apply(dataFrame.col("age")));
```